# How to inverse x>y so that I will have an angled corner?

Tags: javascript

Here's my assignment:

Write a program to draw a red square that is 200 pixels by 200 pixels with this black edge that is 20 pixels wide in the middle and has two diagonal corners (imagine that if the diagonal lines kept going, they would meet in the center of the diagram).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
      var image = new SimpleImage(200, 200)
      for (var p of image.values()){
      var x = p.getX();
      var y = p.getY();
      if (y < 0) {
          p.setRed(255);
      }
      if (x>y) {p.setRed(255);
      }
      if (x > 20) {p.setRed(255);}
      //if (y > x) {p.setRed(255);}

  } 
  print (image);
```

How should I go on about creating a diagonal corner at the bottom left corner? I've created a diagonal corner at the top left corner with the expression x > y. Is there an inverse of this that could produce the diagonal corner at the bottom left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding one more condition to your for loop:

```
if(y>180 && x>(200-y) && x<=20){
    p.setRed(255);
}
```

so the whole code will look like this:

```
var image = new SimpleImage(200, 200)
 for (var p of image.values()){
     var x = p.getX();
     var y = p.getY();
     if (y < 0) {
         p.setRed(255);}
     if (x>y) {p.setRed(255);}
     if (x > 20) {p.setRed(255);}
     if(y > 180 && x>(200-y) && x <=20){
         p.setRed(255);
    }
} 
print (image);
```

Comment: Yes, that will work too, but try to look how the image would change if you writen `p.setGreen(255);` instead of `p.setRed(255);` in that condition.

Comment: And of course that there are much simplier solutions, such as @eddyP suggested (only with inverted "if").

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
var image = new SimpleImage(200, 200)
     for (var p of image.values()){
         var x = p.getX();
         var y = p.getY();

         if (x<=20 & y-x >= 0 & y<=200-x) {
             p.setRed(255);
         }
     }
print (image);
```

Here is the explanation. Draw x and y axis on the picture. Now, there are 4 lines that define the shape you are talking about:

x=0 (the left vertical one)

x = 20 (the right vertical one)

y = x (the main horizontal)

y = 200 - x (the top horizontal)

Now you just need to convert these equalities into inequalities by picking the half of the plane you need, for example x=0 (you need the right hand side) turns into x > 0.

Add all of the equations into the if clause (also notice that x > 0 is not necessary in this situation) and there you go.

Comment: Thanks, but the colors need to be switched on this one.